# Javascript - What's faster, accessing an element directly or setting a variable?

Tags: javascript

I'm working with a HTML `<audio>` element and I was wondering if it's faster (or exactly the same) to reference properties of an element directly vs setting a variable. For example, if I'm using the `audio.ontimeupdate` event and referencing `audio.currentTime` a few times within the function. Which is faster:

```
seconds = (parseInt(track.currentTime % 60)).toLocaleString(undefined, {minimumIntegerDigits: 2});
minutes = parseInt((track.currentTime / 60) % 60);
duration.innerHTML = minutes + ':' + seconds ;
playhead.value = track.currentTime * (1000 / track.duration);
```

or

```
let CurrentTime = track.currentTime;
seconds = (parseInt(CurrentTime % 60)).toLocaleString(undefined, {minimumIntegerDigits: 2});
minutes = parseInt((CurrentTime / 60) % 60);
duration.innerHTML = minutes + ':' + seconds ;
playhead.value = CurrentTime * (1000 / track.duration);
```

Or is there no difference at all? Obviously this updates multiple times per second, which is why I was wondering.

I only ask because when I'm accessing DOM elements, which obviously is different, I set a variable if used more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or is there no difference at all?

No difference at all in the vast majority of situations. If there was a difference, it would only be detectable if this section of code was run unreasonably frequently - thousands of times a second.

But even in such a case, the bottleneck would be the

```
duration.innerHTML =
```

part, since DOM manipulation is much, much more expensive.

Unless this code runs unreasonably frequently, it's not worth worrying about. IMO, better to write code that's as maintainable as possible without worrying much about performance.

If you *were* to optimize the performance of this section of code, I'd recommend saving the `innerHTML` value so you don't unconditionally run

```
duration.innerHTML = minutes + ':' + seconds ;
```

every time, but only when the section needs to be updated. (Or utilize a framework like React that automatically optimizes this for you.)

Comment: Thanks for the response, that's what I figured, but I though it would be worth an ask!

Answer (score 0):

@CertainPerformance is right in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69023545/8154765). This is a micro-optimization that would be premature on a portion of code that runs only once per second.

On the other hand,

1. Repeating `parseInt` is a huge performance bottleneck. Is `track.currentTime` a string? It shouldn't be if it represents a number. I'm assuming `track.currentTime` is the number of seconds of playback.
2. Using `innerHTML` is a horrible mistake. If it would use an external input, it would even lead to security issues. You don't need to set the HTML contents, you just want to set the text of an element, and generally this is how you'd do it:

   ```
    duration.textContent = `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
   ```

   <sup>(I also used template literals if only for greater convenience.)</sup>

   However, in order to avoid creating a new text node on each tick of the clock, you might want to manage a `Text` node separately.

Here's it:

```
const durationTextNode = document.createTextNode();

duration.appendChild(durationTextNode);

function onTick(track) {

    const trackProgress = track.currentTime * (1000 / track.duration);
    const seconds = track.currentTime % 60;
    const minutes = track.currentTime / 60 | 0;

    durationTextNode.data = `${minutes}:${seconds.toLocaleString(undefined, { minimumIntegerDigits: 2 })}`;
    playhead.value = trackProgress;
}
```